# Does translation image augmentation to reduce overfitting on fully convolutional networks make sense?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was wondering if it makes sense to randomly translate an input image during training on a fully convolutional network (e.g. FCN or SegNet, in general networks without fully connected layers at the end) how it is often done when training CNNs to reduce overfitting.

Since they only consist of convolutional layers that do weight sharing across their width and height to me it seems to not have any affect doing random translations.